# Center ImageView vertically to TextView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an ImageView (the clock image in the screen shot below) that I'd like to center vertically to the timestamp text ("2 hours ago" in the image) no matter what the text size.

[image]

I've tried `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` but it has no effect.

I've included the layout code below. What would be the right way to center the clock (id createdTimeImage) vertically to the timestamp text (id createdTime) in a RelativeLayout? Appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fromPictureSection"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/square_shape_grey_border"
    android:padding="1dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fromPicture"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:contentDescription="@null" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fromName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fromPictureSection"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="12dip"
    android:textAppearance="@style/bodyTextStyle" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/createdTimeImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/fromName"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fromPictureSection"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:paddingBottom="0dip"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingTop="0dip"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/clock" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/createdTime"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/fromName"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/createdTimeImage"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="2dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/smallGreyTextStyle" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initialize an image to the `textview` itself

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/createdTime"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/fromName"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/createdTimeImage"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:paddingLeft="2dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:textAppearance="@style/smallGreyTextStyle"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/clock" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this way.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/fromPictureSection"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:padding="1dip"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fromPicture"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:contentDescription="@null" />
</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
android:id="@+id/fromName"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fromPictureSection"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:text="some meore text"
android:paddingLeft="5dip"
android:paddingRight="10dip"
android:paddingTop="12dip" />
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fromPictureSection"
android:layout_below="@id/fromName"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/createdTimeImage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:contentDescription="@null"
android:paddingBottom="0dip"
android:paddingLeft="5dip"
android:paddingTop="0dip"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/createdTime"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:text="some text here"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="2dip"
android:paddingRight="10dip"
android:paddingTop="0dp" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```